# Как можно остановить такой таймер

Tags: java

вот код таймера, его нужно остановить, и после возобновить

```
 new java.util.Timer().schedule(new TimerTask(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                              }
        },1000*2,1000*2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Timer t = new Timer(); 
TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() { 
@Override public void run() { 
// some code
}; 
} 
t.schedule(tt,1000*2,1000*2);
```

Остановка:

```
tt.cancel(); 
t.cancel();
```

Comment: а как возобновить работу таймера?

Comment: Создавать новый. Возобновить уже остановленный нельзя никак.

Comment: Можете попробовать на англоязычном stackoverflow посмотреть по ключевым словам start stop timer или pause continue timer java. Там есть и другие варианты

Comment: блин, просто у меня выдает ошибку `java.lang.IllegalStateException` я думаю, что дело в таймере, но походу, нет

Comment: Чтобы понять откуда ошибка, нужно выкладывать явно больше кода. И это уже совсем другой вопрос. Думаю лучше его задавать отдельно